# How can I fix this responsive navigation bug?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, media-queries

I am banging my head as I am trying to get my responsive navigation to work correctly but I am encountering a bug that really irks me and I just want to know what is the best and cleanest way to solve it. You can see this live on [CodePen](http://cdpn.io/IwLec)

What I have set up is a centered navigation and a logo in the middle and I have margins to surround the logo, all of this is in a media query

```
/* Desktop specific nav
 =====================================================*/
  @media (min-width: 45em) {
 }
```

the problem comes in when I use a media query to display my mobile navigation (what I was trying to do was get rid of the margins so it will display in a block). You can see the bug if you resize your browser right around when it is supposed to change to mobile (you'll notice the "contact" somewhere at the bottom and the margins messed up, I am trying to get rid of this entirely so it goes straight from desktop to mobile without that little glitch)

```
  /* Mobile nav
 =====================================================*/

  @media (max-width: 44.99999999em) {
 }
```

My complete markup

```
<header class="main"> 
      <nav class="nav-collapse" >


       <a href="#about" class="main_link first">ABOUT</a>
       <a href="#skills" class="main_link">PORTFOLIO</a>
       <a href="#" class="sprite-main_logo sprite">LOGO</a>
       <a href="#section_about " class="main_link">BLOG</a>
       <a href="#contact" class="main_link last">CONTACT</a>


      </nav> 

</header>
```

CSS

```
   @media (min-width: 45.0000em) {

      header a.main_link {
      display: inline-block;
      width: 80px;
      margin-right: 40px;
      margin-left: 40px;
      vertical-align: bottom;
      font-size: 18px;
      line-height: 1.278;
      font-size: 1.125rem;
      text-decoration: none;
      color: #000;
      font-family: 'PT Sans Narrow', sans-serif;
     }

      header.main>div {
      background: #ffffff;
      padding: 30px 0px 40px 0px;
      box-shadow: 0 2px 0 2px rgba(242, 242, 242, 0.75);
    }

      header.main {
      text-align: center;
    }

      header a.sprite-main_logo {
      display: inline-block;
      vertical-align: bottom;
      margin: 0px 89px;
    }


      header a.main_link.last {
      margin-right: 0;
    }

      header a.main_link.first {
      margin-left: 0;
    }


}

  @media (max-width: 44.99999999em) {

   .nav-collapse,
   .nav-collapse * {
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    }

    .nav-collapse,
    .nav-collapse  {
        list-style: none;
        width: 100%;
        float: left;
        position: relative;
        margin-bottom: 10px;
        display: block;


        }

    .nav-collapse a {
        float: left;
        width: 100%;
        border-bottom: 1px solid #f4f4f4;
        margin-bottom: 5px;
        padding-bottom: 10px;
        padding-top: 10px;

            }

    .nav-collapse a:last-child {
        border-bottom: none;
    }

    .nav-collapse a:nth-child(3) {
        display: none;
    }

    .nav-collapse a {
        color: #444;
        text-decoration: none;
        width: 100%;
        background: #ffffff;
        padding-left: 10px;
    }
```

Thanks for viewing!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `header a.main_link` You are using `display:inline-block` so you're white space is being included in the width.  You have a few options to fix it:

1. Delete all white-space between elements in your HTML.
2. Set the font-size to zero on `.nav-collapse`.
3. Use `display: block` and float your menu items.
4. Compensate for the space with negative margins on your `.nav-collapse a`

I personally prefer option 3, but it's really up to you.

#### UPDATE

I'm glad you got it working with option three. But just for the record, here is a working demo which uses inline-block:  [DEMO](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/bAost/).  I struggled with this for a bit, and in the end I found that there was actually a left/right margin being added to `<body>`.  So I added:

```
body{
  margin:0 !important;
}
```

And that did it.

Comment: If I used option 1, how exactly would I do that with the nav

Comment: You just go into your HTML and delete all the white-space in the areas between all the tags.  It's pretty simple.  Your code will just not be formatted so nicely.  Here is a good link about the issue you are having http://davidwalsh.name/remove-whitespace-inline-block.

Comment: ok I have done so but when I resize, there is still a point where the desktop nav shows with the "contact" link out of place.

Comment: Do you have another demo?

Comment: Ok, that seemed to work, thanks a lot, and also my white space is fixed as well using option 3.

Answer (score 0):

Your `a` elements are inline-block so the white space counts. You can either delete all the whitespace in your html or do the following hack:

```
.nav-collapse {
    letter-spacing: -0.31em;
}
.nav-collapse a {
    letter-spacing: normal;
}
```